# Laravel Fortify Email Verification failing

Tags: laravel, fortify

I am using Laravel 8 with Fortify.

Everything is working Fine so far apart from email verification.

**The Issue**

1. When a user registers successfully they receive an email containing a signed url.
2. When the url is clicked,  the user is redirected to the login page.
3. The user signs in.
4. verified_at field in db is not updated

Here is a generated link from the email
`https://certhub.test/email/verify/1/7c9f29d87b505da773415b7e0369368e6eaf5fa6?expires=1643801371&signature=a255a0f05fcdb9a23cb7dba392e39317db3cd6657b69d7799c4840008d1633e0`

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good 2 days to fix mine and my problem was I had 'same_site' set to strict in my `sessions.php` and changing to lax did the job for me.